# why $(which python3) is not the default python3 when running script?

Tags: python, bash, macos, shell

It seems that the default executed python3 is the stock one while `which python3` shows the one installed via `macport`.

```
$ which python3
/opt/local/bin/python3

python3 -c 'import sys;print(sys.executable)'
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3
$ $(which python3) -c 'import sys;print(sys.executable)'
/opt/local/bin/python3

$ echo $PATH
/Users/jack/.nvm/versions/node/v8.4.0/bin:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/jack/.yarn/bin:/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin
```

So why I got this weird thing?

Comment: Have you changed your path recently? Then the old path is being cached: [How do I clear Bash's cache of paths to executables?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/5609)

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks very much. I think it's the path cached problem. After `hash -d python3`, problem disappeared.